# Avoiding Amazon Lex "Cold Start"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm building a Voice Assistant with Amazon Connect. The Assistant make use of a bunch of Lex Bots.
I have the Assistant practically finished, but want to solve a "error" that makes a user's bad experience.

The first time I execute the Voice Assistant (making a proof call), Amazon Lex's bots have a long delay on it's response. Only happens at first time Amazon Lex's bots are executed (if the Assistant start a second conversation, the delay it's not happening).

Looking for information, I found this:

[Amazon Lex's Cold Start solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKVWU.png)

Then I tried to develop a Lambda Function to apply this Bot Lex pre-warm. This is the code on lambda_handler():

```
lex_client = boto3.client('lexv2-runtime')

# Itero sobre cada uno de los Bots asignados en el diccionario anterior
for idBot, caracteristicasBot in dictBotsLex.items():
    
    try:

        response = lex_client.recognize_text(
                botAliasId= caracteristicasBot['botAlias'],  # Reemplaza con el alias ID de tu bot
                botId=idBot,
                localeId= 'es_ES',  # Reemplaza con el código de idioma de tu bot si es diferente
                sessionId= caracteristicasBot['userId'],  # Puedes usar un ID de usuario único aquí
                text= caracteristicasBot['inputText']  # Un mensaje de prueba para activar el bot
            )

        print('El bot {} se ha ejecutado correctamente'.format(idBot))
        
        
        
    except Exception as e:
        
        print("Error al llamar al Bot {} de Lex. Causa del error ==> {} .".format(idBot, e))

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': 'Llamadas a los bots de Lex realizadas con éxito'
}
```

The code generates no errors, but the cold start on my bots has not dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I had tried to execute the Lambda function with a cron, which executes the Lambda  every hour. The Cold Start doesn't dissapear.  However, if I execute the Lambda with a test proof, and then I make a proof call, the Cold Start dissapear.

```
lex_client = boto3.client('lexv2-runtime')


for clave, valor in dictBotsLex.items():
    
    
    try:


        lex_request = {
            'botId': clave,
            'botAliasId': valor['botAlias'],
            'localeId': 'es_ES',
            'sessionId': valor['userId'],
            'text': valor['inputText']
        }
        
        
        lex_response = lex_client.recognize_text(**lex_request)
        
        time.sleep(5)  # Añado un retraso para permitir que el bot cargue 
se active
        
        print('Lex V2 bot {} warmed up successfully'.format(clave))
        
    except Exception as e:
        
        print(f'Ha ocurrido un error el ejecutar el bot {clave} ==>', e)
        
        
    
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': 'Lex V2 bots warmed up successfully.'
    }
```

I think that the implemented delay allows Lex Bots to activate, solving the Cold Start "error".

The code works when trying to execute the Lambda function normally. However, if Lambda function is executed by a Eventbridge cron, it makes no effect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).